# Web workers returns only one message and no message afterwards despite using setTimeout

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote some code that is supposed to receive web worker messages from an external js file (workers_demo.js) and place it between output tags. The javascript is such that the first message is received upon clicking a button and messages are to be received every second (so the html between the  tags increments by 1 every second). However, the problem is that the number increments to 1 but does not continue to increment after that. The following is the main file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src= "jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined"){
                var w;
                $("button#start").click(function(){
                    if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
                        w = new Worker("workers_demo.js");
                    } 
                    w.onmessage = function(event){
                        console.log("I have received a message"); 
                        $("output#number").html(event.data);
                    }
                });
                $("button#stop").click(function(){
                    w.terminate();
                });
            }else{
                //fallback code
                $("output#number").html("Sorry no web workers.");
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <output id="number"></output>
    <button id = "start">Start Counting</button>
    <button id = "stop">Stop Counting</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And the web worker file referred to in the code above :

```
var output_number = 0;
function increment_numbers() {
output_number++;
postMessage(output_number); 
setTimeout("increment_numbers",1000);
}
increment_numbers();
```

What is causing the number to increment the first time but not subsequently?

Comment: loose the quotes in the `setTimeout`: change `setTimeout("increment_numbers",1000);` to `setTimeout(increment_numbers,1000);`

Comment: Pass a function reference to setTimeout, not a string. Passed strings are evaluated as JS, but the code in the string doesn't do anything (it doesn't call the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already said this in a comment, but I'll just answer it so people know the question has an answer:

```
setTimeout("increment_numbers",1000);
```

should be

```
setTimeout(increment_numbers,1000); //no quotes around the function name
```